# Retrieving error on one to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Been learning laravel for 4 days and im trying to fix this error for 2 hours and i cant still fix it. I can save on one to many relationship but i cant retrieve data i think there something wrong with the relationship. Im trying to retrieve posts on user using this line but im getting not empty results on users but empty result on posts. Same thing happening on categories and posts which is many to many relationship but i cant save on many to many.

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get();
```

ANd im getting an error when i use this the error is

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::posts()

```
 $users = User::where('user_id','=','2')->get();

 $posts = $users->posts()->get();
```

Heres my user Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

       protected $primarykey = 'user_id';
        protected $table = 'users';

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Post");
    }
}
```

Heres my posts Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{

    protected $primarykey = 'id';
        protected $table = 'posts';

    public function post_validation_rules(){
        return [
                'post_title' => 'required|min:5|unique:posts',
                'post_body' => 'required'
            ];
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }

     public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Categories Post

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $primarykey = 'category_id';
        protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id');
    }
}

Database

Posts Table
id
user_id
post_title
post_body
createad_date
updated_date

Users Table
user_id
username
email
pass
createad_date
updated_date
```

Comment: do you have the user_id in post table?

Comment: yeah i have it hold on im going to post my db structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare the field that have the relation between your tables then, for example:

`$this->hasMany(App\Post::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');`

Laravel is searching for a field `id` in User table but it does not exist. so with this way you will tell it that the field you look is `user_id`

Comment: It worked!!! thanks. I was doing the wrong thing i  was doing this $this->hasMany(App\Post::class, 'post_id', 'id');   I almost gave up can it also work on many to many?

Comment: yes just declare each time what fields to 'connect'

Comment: Accept the answer in  order to close the question please.

Answer (score 2):

You can only call relations on a single object, not on an entire collection. `$users` is a collection of `User` objects.

If you want a single user object, use the `first()` function to get the first `User` object that matches.

```
$user = User::where('user_id','=','2')->first();
$posts = $user->posts;
```

**Update:**
To get the posts directly in the user object, you need to use the `with` function:

```
$user = User::with('posts')->where('user_id','=','2')->first();
```

Comment: Oh thanx now i get it now im only getting empty row

Comment: Than you probably don't have a `User` with `user_id` `2`.

Comment: i have it im only getting empty result on post model. 
[code]
 
    "user_id" => 2
    "username" => "levi"
    "email" => "levi@gmail.com"
    "pass" => "leviiiii"
    "created_at" => "2017-10-11 14:35:38"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-11 14:35:39"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "username" => "levi"
    "email" => "levi@gmail.com"
    "pass" => "leviiiii"
    "created_at" => "2017-10-11 14:35:38"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-11 14:35:39"
  ]
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "posts" => Collection {#163 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  [code]

Comment: To get the posts directly in the object, you need to use the `with` function to eager load this relation.

Comment: I tried but still empty i guess im doing something wrong with my relationship. 
  #original: array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "username" => "levi"
    "email" => "levi@gmail.com"
    "pass" => "leviiiii"
    "created_at" => "2017-10-11 14:35:38"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-11 14:35:39"
  ]
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "posts" => Collection {#165 ▼
      #items: []
    }

Comment: Have your tried to output the posts only (`dd($user->posts)`)? And are you sure this user has posts?